# Search from SqlDataSource show in Gridview asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, search, gridview

I have problem about my label is not lost when search data that have in SQL Server.

Here is my code

```
protected void btnSearchAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //  BindAbb();
        string search1 = txtSearch.Text;
        string Filter = "";

        if (SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand.Contains(String.Empty))
        {
            lblOutput.Visible = true;
            lblOutput.Text = "Not Found";
        }

        if (search1 != "")
        {
            Filter = Filter + "AbbCode like '%" + search1 + "%' and ";
        }

        if (Filter.Length > 0)
        {
            string finalFilter = Filter.Remove(Filter.Length - 4, 3);
            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = finalFilter;
        }
        else
        {
            lblOutput.Visible = false;
            grd_AbbCode.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

When I search data that don't have in SQL Server, it's ok when "Not Found" is show on my page.

http://www.mx7.com/i/ece/0u4iX8.jpg

but when I search data that I do have in SQL Server, "Not found" is still show together with my data.

http://www.mx7.com/i/125/AxrUNz.jpg

I solve it in my way but it still show.

How to solve it? Thank you so much.

Comment: *when I search data that don't have in MS SQL it's ok when "Not Found"* **You getting it wrong, here both screen displayed Connection timed out**

Comment: Set EnableViewState= "false" for the label

Comment: <asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server" Text="Label" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Label> I set it but it still show